# Converting a subset of factors in a dataframe to numeric using as.numeric(levels(f))[f]

Tags: r, syntax

I have a dataframe with 100 variables, of which I would like a subset, say dataframename[,30:50] to be converted to their original numeric values (1,2,3,4,5).

I know that I should use `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` when I convert a factor, but I can only make this work when I convert the factors one at a time. I would like to convert them all at once.

This wont work:

```
as.numeric(levels(dataframename[,30:50]))[dataframename[,30:50]]
```

neither will this:

```
sapply(dataframename[,30:50],as.numeric(levels(dataframename[,30:50]))    
[dataframename[,30:50]]
```

Any ideas or stuff I should read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a smaller example but the idea should hold.  You can use `lapply` to apply your conversion to each column of your data frame and then just replace those columns directly.

```
# make example data
dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(as.data.frame(matrix(seq(2*3), ncol = 3)), factor))

factorconvert <- function(f){as.numeric(levels(f))[f]}
dat[, 2:3] <- lapply(dat[, 2:3], factorconvert)
dat
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  3  5
#2  2  4  6
#str(dat)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ V1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2
# $ V2: num  3 4
# $ V3: num  5 6
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I have a feeling I will be using lapply() a lot in the future :)   (i can't vote your answer up because my reputation is too low)

Answer (score 1):

I like `@Dason`'s answer. There is a way to do this in one line only, where you apply the de-factoring to only the columns of interest and use an anonymous function, like:

```
dataframename[,30:50] <- lapply(dataframename[,30:50], function(f) as.numeric(levels(f))[f])
```

Note that the columns do not have to be contiguous, i.e. you can use the typical c(col1:col10, col20) subsetting syntax.