# geom_crossbar produces a plot with inappropriate y scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

It is difficult to describe my problem without attaching an image of the plot. I have two groups of data, one with two observations having mean around 1 and error around 1.5; the other has two observations with mean around 30 and error around 2.

But in the plot the bars overlap and the y-axis tick marks are out of order:

0; 0.1; 1; 1.7; 2; 27.8; 29.3; 29.8; 3.2; 31.3; 31.8; 33.3

Data and code (dataframe my.data):

```
my.data <- structure(list(factor1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("oil1", "oil2"), class = "factor"), factor2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("prod1", "prod2"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.7, 1, 29.8, 31.3), err = c(1.5, 1, 2, 2), min = c(0.2, 0, 27.8, 29.3), max = c(3.2, 2, 31.8, 33.3)), .Names = c("factor1", "factor2", "value", "err", "min", "max"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

    # Plots
      p1 <- ggplot(data=my.data, aes(x=factor2, fill=factor1))
      p2 <- p1 + geom_crossbar(aes(y=value, ymin=min, ymax=max), position = position_dodge(width = 0.66), width=0.6)
      p2
```

I would greatly apreciate help on this, I have been stuck on it for two days now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see overlapping using your data and your script.

Comment: I am using RStudio ver. 0.98.1062; R ver. 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) and ggplot2 ver. 1.0.0, if it can be of any help.

Comment: RStudio has nothing to do with this. I used the same version of ggplot2.

Comment: I also tried saving the plot directly as .png file, but the same thing happens. Pascal, could you parhaps post here an image of your results using my data and script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data and your script I get:
[image]

Comment: Which is what I want, yet I cannot get it. I'm even more stumped now.

Comment: Now I made it work, but it's still strange. Using the code `my.data <- structure(list(factor1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("oil1", "oil2"), class = "factor"), factor2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("prod1", "prod2"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.7, 1, 29.8, 31.3), err = c(1.5, 1, 2, 2), min = c(0.2, 0, 27.8, 29.3), max = c(3.2, 2, 31.8, 33.3)), .Names = c("factor1", "factor2", "value", "err", "min", "max"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))` you provided the plot turns out OK. But if the dataframe is created from a .csv using `read.table`, not.

Comment: You need to check the output of `read.table`, particularly the class of the columns, i.e. whether numbers are really numeric. There is an option for that in `read.table` to avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'll look into that issue

Comment: The problem is converting a subset of a dataframe to numeric, as it is shown for this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868122/converting-a-subset-of-factors-in-a-dataframe-to-numeric-using-as-numericlevels, correct?

Comment: Alright, thanks to Pascal now my script works as desired. I had the answers I needed.