# How to add data labels at the top of crossbars using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, label

I have a code that does a nice job of plotting a crossbar plot from a dataframe, where the bottom and top of the bar represent respectively min and max of observed values, and the the cross line represents the average.

Now I have been asked to add data labels for the average value at the top of the bars, and that is more difficult than I imagined.
I tried to adjust the label position using hjust, vjust, position_dodge and position_stack - but nothing works as I need

Anybody here can give suggestions?

Edit - 
Example of data and code for the crossbar plot can be found at this link: [geom_crossbar produces a plot with inappropriate y scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315568/geom-crossbar-produces-a-plot-with-inappropriate-y-scale)

What am I unhappy with? The labels are all over the place, I am unable to put them in any specified position. While I (well, the manager to whom I report) want them  at the top of the bars.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, using the data from the prior SO question, that puts the means at the top of the boxes, but the lower two are not aligned.

```
my.data <- structure(list(factor1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("oil1", "oil2"),
          class = "factor"), factor2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("prod1", "prod2"),
          class = "factor"), value = c(1.7, 1, 29.8, 31.3), err = c(1.5, 1, 2, 2),
          min = c(0.2, 0, 27.8, 29.3), max = c(3.2, 2, 31.8, 33.3)), .Names = c("factor1", "factor2",
          "value", "err", "min", "max"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

ggplot(data=my.data, aes(x=factor2, fill=factor1)) + 
  geom_crossbar(aes(y=value, ymin=min, ymax=max), position = position_dodge(width = 0.66), width=0.6) +
  geom_text(aes(y = max, label = value, hjust = -0.6, vjust = -0.4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks lawyer, but I agreed with the boss that the labels do not have to be strictly at the top. Other positions are good as long as it is clear which line the label refers too and the label is easily readable. So, much ado about nothing.

Comment: Well, good solution for both of you.  Does that mean you won't accept the answer or upvote it?

Comment: Understood, but if you accept what I did, click on the check mark to accept it for Stack Overflow purposes.